# Problem in exporting animation for website

Tags: animation, export, gltf

i've decided recently to learn blender.
I made a project (a simple animation), and i would like to put it on a React website.
I tried to export the animation in gltf (i already knew the issues with the color system), but the gltf does not export metaballs. I tried to use a sprite sheet system, but there are too many frames and each single frame is too big (i would like to preserve the hughest resolution possible).
Any advice?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57541/19307